# How to estimate camera pose according to a projective transformation matrix of two consecutive frames?

Tags: graphics, camera, computer-vision, projective-geometry

I'm working on the kitti visual odometry dataset. I use projective transformation to register two 2D consecutive frames([see projective transformation example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELwyH.png)
). I want to know how this 3*3 projective transformation matrix is related to the ground truth poses provided by the kitti dataset.

This dataset gives the ground truth poses (trajectory) for the sequences, which is described below:

Folder 'poses':

The folder 'poses' contains the ground truth poses (trajectory) for the
first 11 sequences. This information can be used for training/tuning your
method. Each file xx.txt contains a N x 12 table, where N is the number of
frames of this sequence. Row i represents the i'th pose of the left camera
coordinate system (i.e., z pointing forwards) via a 3x4 transformation
matrix. The matrices are stored in row aligned order (the first entries
correspond to the first row), and take a point in the i'th coordinate
system and project it into the first (=0th) coordinate system. Hence, the
translational part (3x1 vector of column 4) corresponds to the pose of the
left camera coordinate system in the i'th frame with respect to the first
(=0th) frame. Your submission results must be provided using the same data
format.

Some samples of the given groud-truth poses:

1.000000e+00 9.043680e-12 2.326809e-11 5.551115e-17 9.043683e-12 1.000000e+00 2.392370e-10 3.330669e-16 2.326810e-11 2.392370e-10 9.999999e-01 -4.440892e-16

9.999978e-01 5.272628e-04 -2.066935e-03 -4.690294e-02 -5.296506e-04 9.999992e-01 -1.154865e-03 -2.839928e-02 2.066324e-03 1.155958e-03 9.999971e-01 8.586941e-01

9.999910e-01 1.048972e-03 -4.131348e-03 -9.374345e-02 -1.058514e-03 9.999968e-01 -2.308104e-03 -5.676064e-02 4.128913e-03 2.312456e-03 9.999887e-01 1.716275e+00

9.999796e-01 1.566466e-03 -6.198571e-03 -1.406429e-01 -1.587952e-03 9.999927e-01 -3.462706e-03 -8.515762e-02 6.193102e-03 3.472479e-03 9.999747e-01 2.574964e+00

9.999637e-01 2.078471e-03 -8.263498e-03 -1.874858e-01 -2.116664e-03 9.999871e-01 -4.615826e-03 -1.135202e-01 8.253797e-03 4.633149e-03 9.999551e-01 3.432648e+00

9.999433e-01 2.586172e-03 -1.033094e-02 -2.343818e-01 -2.645881e-03 9.999798e-01 -5.770163e-03 -1.419150e-01 1.031581e-02 5.797170e-03 9.999299e-01 4.291335e+00

9.999184e-01 3.088363e-03 -1.239599e-02 -2.812195e-01 -3.174350e-03 9.999710e-01 -6.922975e-03 -1.702743e-01 1.237425e-02 6.961759e-03 9.998991e-01 5.148987e+00

9.998890e-01 3.586305e-03 -1.446384e-02 -3.281178e-01 -3.703403e-03 9.999605e-01 -8.077186e-03 -1.986703e-01 1.443430e-02 8.129853e-03 9.998627e-01 6.007777e+00

9.998551e-01 4.078705e-03 -1.652913e-02 -3.749547e-01 -4.231669e-03 9.999484e-01 -9.229794e-03 -2.270290e-01 1.649063e-02 9.298401e-03 9.998207e-01 6.865477e+00

9.998167e-01 4.566671e-03 -1.859652e-02 -4.218367e-01 -4.760342e-03 9.999347e-01 -1.038342e-02 -2.554151e-01 1.854788e-02 1.047004e-02 9.997731e-01 7.724036e+00

9.997738e-01 5.049868e-03 -2.066463e-02 -4.687329e-01 -5.289072e-03 9.999194e-01 -1.153730e-02 -2.838096e-01 2.060470e-02 1.164399e-02 9.997198e-01 8.582886e+00

9.997264e-01 5.527315e-03 -2.272922e-02 -5.155474e-01 -5.816781e-03 9.999025e-01 -1.268908e-02 -3.121547e-01 2.265686e-02 1.281782e-02 9.996611e-01 9.440275e+00

9.996745e-01 6.000540e-03 -2.479692e-02 -5.624310e-01 -6.345160e-03 9.998840e-01 -1.384246e-02 -3.405416e-01 2.471098e-02 1.399530e-02 9.995966e-01 1.029896e+01

9.996182e-01 6.468772e-03 -2.686440e-02 -6.093087e-01 -6.873365e-03 9.998639e-01 -1.499561e-02 -3.689250e-01 2.676374e-02 1.517453e-02 9.995266e-01 1.115757e+01

9.995562e-01 7.058450e-03 -2.894213e-02 -6.562052e-01 -7.530449e-03 9.998399e-01 -1.623192e-02 -3.973964e-01 2.882292e-02 1.644266e-02 9.994492e-01 1.201541e+01

9.995095e-01 5.595311e-03 -3.081450e-02 -7.018788e-01 -6.093682e-03 9.998517e-01 -1.610315e-02 -4.239119e-01 3.071983e-02 1.628303e-02 9.993953e-01 1.286965e+01

Answer (score 2):

The common name for your "projective transformation" is homography. In a calibrated setup (i.e. if you know your camera's field of view or, equivalently, its focal length) a homography can be decomposed into 3D rotation and translation, the latter only up to scale. The decomposition algorithm additionally produces the normal to the 3D plane inducting the homography. The algorithm has up to 4 solutions, of which only one is feasible when you apply additional constraints, such as that the matched image points triangulate in front of the camera, and that the general direction of the translation match a known prior.

More information about the method is in a well-known [paper by Malis and Vargas](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00174036v3/document). There is an implementation in OpenCV, under the name [decomposeHomographyMat](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposehomographymat).